# Find URL in XML based on other URL and redirect

Tags: php, xml

I’m trying to redirect visitors who enter a (shortened) url on domain A, to the longer url version on domain B. A bit like using bit.ly, but then with custom domain names.
The destination URL's on domain B can be found in a sitemap.xml

For example: A visitor enters www.domain-a.com/abc-123/

There would be a match for ‘abc-123’ in this url: www.domain-b.com/subdirectory/abc-123-long-seo-friendly-addition/

What I have so far is an addition in .htaccess to intercept url strings entered, and not get a 'permission denied'.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The PHP:

```
$shortUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Get the shortened URI from domain-a.
$url = 'https://www.domain-b/sitemap.xml'; // Place XML in a variable.
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url)); // Access XML contents.
```

From there I'm stuck (I'm learning to code). How would I find a matching URL in the XML and redirect users to that URL?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're storing the mapping in an XML file and not in a database table?

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the structure of that xml. Things you might want to look up: traversing nodes in xml / regular expressions

Comment: @PatrickQ No, not really. The XML accumulates all the URL's on domain B. But they are in a database. I'm feeling noobie already...

Comment: @bebobalula  A database table would likely be easier to maintain and search.  Especially if they're _already_ in a database.

Comment: @PatrickQ Sounds like a good idea! I'll investigate how to connect and search a database with PHP. I'll 'relaunch' this question if I get stuck with my newly gathered wisdom. Thanks.

Comment: I'm almost there! Here the quest continues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177222/use-php-variable-in-mysql-query